# Vector Differential in specific form

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, information-theory

for the operator: $\Delta A(t) = A(t+1)-A(t)$, let :

$$
\Delta C = \sum^{T-1}_{t=0} [~~H(\pi(t+1)~|~\mu(t+1))~~ - ~~H(\pi(t)~|~\mu(t+1))~~]
$$
Where $H (\pi(t+1)|\mu(t+1)) = \sum^n_{i=1}\pi_i(t) \log \frac{\pi_i(t)}{\mu_i(t+1}$ is the relative entropy.

This implies that:
$$
C(t) = H(\pi(t)~|~\mu(t+1))
$$

Now, I am trying to show that equating the first order taylor expansion of $C$ as a function of s to a quantity $\alpha(t)$ should yield the following:
$$
s:= \frac{\alpha(t)~~\big/~~|~\nabla H(\pi(t)| \mu(t+1)\bullet v)~|~~}{|\mu(t+1) - \pi(t)|}
$$
where $v=\frac{\mu(t+1) - \pi(t)}{|\mu(t+1) - \pi(t)|}$

Now:
$$
C(s) = C(0) + C'(0) ~s\\
=C'(0) ~s
$$
then equating to $\alpha(t)$:

$$
s = \alpha(t) / C'(0)
$$

and I've shown that 
$$
\nabla H = \big(\frac{\partial H}{\partial \pi_1},....,\frac{\partial H}{\partial \pi_n} \big) = (1,...,1) +  \big(\log \frac{\pi_1(s)}{\mu_1(s+1)},...., \big)
$$

I cannot get that value of s though with this working, some intermediate questions. I'm not looking for an entire solution but how would the vector norms come into play at all?